# Deserialization to sub-class without @type field

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Say I've got the usual Animal, Cat extends Animal, Dog extends Animal polymorphic example in Jackson, using @type to discriminate between sub-types:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
})
public abstract class Animal {
    ...
}


public class Cat extends Animal {
    ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

I'm using this in a Spring Boot REST API.

Now I want to de-serialize a Cat from a JSON string that doesn't have the @type included. I know it's a Cat, because that's all this particular REST API call accepts. How do I get Jackson to de-serialize this JSON as a Cat, without it complaining about missing the "@type" field?

I know I could include `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)` in the Cat class, but then when I serialise Cats the won't have the @type field, which I still want.

Do I need to provide a custom deserializer? Can I do that for a single controller method?

Comment: Can you add the controller method code? With the mapper is as simple as `Cat c = mapper.readValue(json, Cat.class);` since it will not use the superclass.

Comment: That was my hope, however doing that throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@type' that is to contain type id`

Comment: same subject discussed as jackson-databind issue on github: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/955